# How to solve error when installing sf package

Tags: r, installation, package, r-sf

I am using a newer Mac laptop with a M1 chip and R version 4.2.2 and get the following error when trying to install `sf` in RStudio. How can I fix this?

```
> install.packages("sf")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.2/sf_1.0-9.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 89952912 bytes (85.8 MB)
====================================
downloaded 62.6 MB

Warning in install.packages :
  downloaded length 65639971 != reported length 89952912
Warning in install.packages :
  URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.2/sf_1.0-9.tgz': Timeout of 60 seconds was reached
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  download from 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.2/sf_1.0-9.tgz' failed
Warning in install.packages :
  download of package ‘sf’ failed
```

If I try installing it in base R, I get:

```
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  download from 'https://mirrors.nics.utk.edu/cran/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.2/sf_1.0-9.tgz' failed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
  downloaded length 57524224 != reported length 89952912
2: In download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
  URL 'https://mirrors.nics.utk.edu/cran/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.2/sf_1.0-9.tgz': Timeout of 60 seconds was reached
Warning in download.packages(pkgs, destdir = tmpd, available = available,  :
  download of package ‘sf’ failed
```

Comment: That looks like a temporary server error maybe? I was able to copy/paste https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.2/sf_1.0-9.tgz in my browser and was able to download the file. Have you tried it multiple times? How long as the error persisted? Are you behind any network firewalls that may be blocking your access to that website?

Comment: Good points. I updated R yesterday and had to reinstall all packages. This is when the error started. That is a good point on the server. I am temporarily at a place that has blocked certain websites like GitHub and Google Drive, so hopefully that is the issue. I will retry in a few days when I return home.

Comment: Note that I was able to get it to work by downloading the .tgz file directly, then installing in R by changing to the directory that housed the file and doing `install.packages("sf_1.0-9.tgz", repos = NULL, type = 'source')`.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered similar issue and solved it downloading the `.tgz` file from https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.2/sf_1.0-9.tgz

Then, I installed it using `install.packages("/Users/XX/Downloads/sf_1.0-9.tgz", repos=NULL, type="source")`